# Is it possible to make Dipotassium Phosphate from Mono-potassium phosphate and potassium hydroxide?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Having fertilizer formulated and asked for 100% Dipotassium phosphate,  the formulator says its reacting mono-potassium phosphate with potassium hydroxide to make it.  Just wanted to double check and be sure this made sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Comment: yes, entirely possible

Comment: Yes,it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, why not?

$$\ce{KH2PO4 + KOH -> K2HPO4 + H2O}$$